# Extension manager crashes on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: gnome-shell-extension, 23.04

I have been using Ubuntu recently and have re-installed Ubuntu on my new HDD because the older one was way too slow. Both still have Ubuntu and are running 23.04,however whenever I open the extension manager it crashes. Here's a [video](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1004686331298992233/1103932756360188004/Screencast_from_2023-05-05_11-29-40.webm)

Re-installing doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using a snap of GNOME Extension Manager. I'd recommend removing it and using the deb package. The snap is unofficial, and seems broken.

```
sudo snap remove gnome-extension-manager
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```